# Show that two subspaces $V$ and $W$ are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

$V = \{(x, y, z) ∈ \Bbb R^³
| x − y + z = 0\}$ and $W = \{(a, a + b, b) ; a, b ∈ \Bbb R\}$.

I need to prove that those two subspaces are equal. I tried something but I'm not really sure about it...

Comment: please show us what you tried

Comment: Well the inclusion W ⊆ V is pretty trivial a-a -b + b = 0 no problem here. But i'm blocking on the inclusion V ⊆  W

Comment: You're probably overthinking the inclusion $V \subseteq W$. Can you write down what you think you need to prove to show this inclusion?

Comment: Using $W\subseteq V$, compare dimensions

Comment: Your first comment above should be included in the question but would anyway not be sufficient. You wrote "I tried something" but still didn't answer about *what* you tried (to prove V⊆W).

Answer (score 3):

The space $V$ can be written as
$$
V = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3| y = x+z\} = \{(x,x+z,z),x\in\mathbb{R}, z\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$
which is exactly $W$, but with different variables name.

Comment: This question does not meet the [standards for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of answering it, why not help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.

Comment: thank you I didn't notice that.. maybe with some more practise I will catch those 
subtleties

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x=y-z$ so we set $a=y-z$. Similarly $z=x-y$ so we set $b=x-y$. So this means $y=z+x$ forces $y=a+b$. This means the solutions of $x-y+z=0$ are of the form $(a,a+b,b)$ and so $V=W$.

Comment: This question does not meet the [standards for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of answering it, why not help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @AnneBauval So more context and include their attempt in the question rather than the comments? Or is the question itself too low quality?  I'm trying to stop answering questions in the comments as well and I'm struggling to strike the right balance.

Comment: So am I! For this particular post, see [my last comment above](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4845248/timeline#comment_10321941).

Answer (score 0):

To prove $V \subseteq W$:

Let $v = (x, y, z) \in V$. Then $x - y + z = 0$. Set $a = x, b = z$, and so $a - y + b = 0 \implies y = a + b$ and hence $v \in W$.

To prove $W \subseteq V$:

Let $w = (a, a+b, b) \in W$. Then with $x = a, y = a+b, z = b$ we have $x - y + z = a - (a + b) + b = 0$ and hence $w \in V$.

Note that almost any time you want to write an inclusion proof for $A \subseteq B$ you should start with "Let $a$ be a generic element of $A$", and show how the condition for being in $A$ satisfies the condition for being in $B$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the [standards for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of answering it, why not help the user by posting [comments suggesting improvements](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4845248/timeline#comment_10321941)? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.